# Axcess single value from from stdClass array object

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I am trying to access an stdClass object array ang print a single value. This is how i would do this with an normal multidimensinal array. How can i accomplish the same thing if the array is an stdClass object?

```
print_r($subscribers[0]['s_courseid']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `stdClass` object array,you have to use `->`

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) and [this](http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass) for more info

Here is an example.

```
$book = new stdClass;
$book->title = "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban";
$book->author = "J. K. Rowling";
$book->publisher = "Arthur A. Levine Books";
$book->amazon_link = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/0439136369/";
```

In your case,

```
$subscribers[0]->s_courseid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastshot, i just figured that out:

```
$subscribers[0]->s_courseid;
```